# Where do I attach the Execute API policy for React App deployed via ECR -> ECS -> ELB?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I wish to secure my API Gateway using AWS IAM Authorization so that only my React Application and users with the correct policy attached can call the endpoints.

I have managed to test that the policy works when I execute via Postman using AWS Signature as the authorisation method, but I'm having trouble applying this policy to my React Application.

The React Application is deployed using CodePipeline to build a container to ECR, then to deploy the application via ECS. The domain routes to the ELB that is mapped to the reverse proxy of the React Application. I just cannot figure out where to attach the policy so that when the API call is made from the webpage, the authorisation is attached to the request. The endpoints are returning a 403 - Missing Authentication Token error (as expected)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching the IAM role to the application's container, I implemented the headers client side. As I'm using Axios, I used the https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4-axios package which creates a request interceptor for the signing. The credentials are from a new user created with the policy attached to allow execute-api.

```
import { aws4Interceptor } from "aws4-axios";

export const postLogin = async () => {
  let response;
  const interceptor = aws4Interceptor(
    {
      region: "your region here",
      service: "execute-api",
    },
    {
      accessKeyId: "from .env",
      secretAccessKey: "from .env",
    }
  );

  axios.interceptors.request.use(interceptor);

  try {
    response = await axios.post( etc.
```

Comment: You discovered the only way to make this work. The React application runs in your user's web browsers, not on a server. All your server does is serve the javascript files to the web browser, which then runs the code. So you can't attach an IAM policy in AWS that will show up in the HTTP requests that come from people's web browsers.